# jquery show-hide DIV with CONTACT FORM 7 dropdown menu (select field)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I am trying to make a dropdown menu (as required field) with CONTACT FORM 7, which is when each option is selected, then a div that contains a certain message (different message on each options) is showing under that dropdown menu.

My Contact Form 7 select field generated code is something like this:

```
[select* menu-163 id:reason include_blank "I want to hire you" "I want to ask you a question" "I want to say hello"]
```

And these 3 sample DIVs, each of them needs to shows up when we move our selection from the first default blank option to any certain defined options:

```
<div id="hire" class="note">I am currently available</div>
<div id="question" class="note">Feel free to ask</div>
<div id="hello" class="note">Get in touch</div>
```

The jquery that I'm using:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/showhidereason.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('.note').hide();
   $('#reason').change(function () {
      $('.note').hide();
      $('#'+$(this).val()).show();
   });
});
</script>
```

**The problem is:**

It seems the jquery code can't get/recognize the ID of the select field, which is `#reason` that I have defined for my CONTACT FORM 7 dropdown menu. That is why my div (hidden messages) are not showing at all when I select any of the dropdown menu option.

The jquery code above is working fine (div/hidden messages are showing up) when **I try making the select field with common HTML code instead** of the generated ones from Contact Form 7, **but then this very select field/dropdown menu is losing the "required effect"** from the contact form validation function (because it's not a Contact Form 7 generated code).

You can see the jquery code is working, as well as the "required effect" is failing at this sample webpage: http://lavertibrands.com/contact/

So, I decided to stick with the generated select field/dropdown code from Contact Form 7, but having this issue on how to make the jquery code recognize the `#reason` ID in order to make the div (hidden messages) shows up.

Is there any advice for me to make those div showing up? Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The selected value of the "reason" field does not correspond to the #id of your divs.

Try this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.note').hide();

  $('#reason').change(function () {
    $('.note').hide();
    var val = $(this).val();
    $('#hire').hide();
    $('#question').hide();
    $('#hello').hide();
    if (val == 'I want to hire you') {
      $('#hire').show();
    }
    else if (val == 'I want to ask you a question') {
      $('#question').show();
    }
    else if (val == 'I want to say hello') {
      $('#hello').show();
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

See [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hVR22/1/)

Comment: It seems to take an effect, but there is a problem. No matter which options that I selected, it will only show the div/hidden message that is defined for `#hire` ID to display. After that, any other options that I selected, there is nothing change. Even if I re-select the default blank option, the div/hidden message for `#hire` is not going to hide again.

Comment: It works, just got it fixed..thanks to your help and detailed knowledge. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can change `div` `id`s with values, equal to `option` values. Then on `change` in `select` find needed `div` using `option` `value`

## HTML:

```
<select id="reason">
    <option>...</option>
    <option value="I want to hire you">I want to hire you</option>
    <option value="I want to ask you a question">I want to ask you a question</option>
    <option value="I want to say hello">I want to say hello</option>
</select>

<div id="I want to hire you" class="note">I am currently available</div>
<div id="I want to ask you a question" class="note">Feel free to ask</div>
<div id="I want to say hello" class="note">Get in touch</div>
```

## JavaScript:

```
$('.note').hide();

$(document).on("change", "#reason", function () {
  $('.note').hide();
  var neededId = $(this).val();
  var divToShow = $(".note").filter("[id='" + neededId + "']");
  divToShow.show();
});
```

## Demo is [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/n1k1ch/MyP8C/1/)

Comment: How about the "required field" effect that I would like to have? Also, I think I can make a dropdown menu with a standard HTML for a Contact Form 7, because it seems to 'cancel' the required field or validation function of the Contact Form 7.<br/>It seems because we define the option-1 to be "...", so it will replace the `include_blank` that the Contact Form 7 has provided, and because of first option is not considered as a blank option anymore, then the "required field" validation is canceled.

Comment: Are you able to change `div` `id`s?

Comment: sorry for previous typo. I meant: Also, I think I CAN'T make a dropdown menu

Comment: Is these codes will make the dropdown to be a required field? I would like this dropdown menu as a required field. As I said, by defining `<option>...</option>` it will cancel the `include_blank` originally from CONTACT FORM 7 plugin, which will also cancel the required field validation function. The `include_blank` will be seen as `<option value>---</option>` in Chrome's inspect element feature. But if we copy it as HTML, then paste it into notepad (for example), it will shown as `<option value="">---</option>`

Comment: Is Dropdown menu (`select`) generated by Wordpress? Are `<div>`s created by you by writing html code?

Comment: Dropdown menu is generated by Contact Form 7 plugin, which the code is `[select* menu-163 id:reason include_blank "I want to hire you" "I want to ask you a question" "I want to say hello"]`. The `include_blank` define the default-first blank option of the dropdown menu. And yes, the `<div>`s are created by writing html code.

Comment: Please see: http://lavertibrands.com/contact-drop-test/ (dropdown menu in this test-page still has the required validation). And then see this one: http://lavertibrands.com/contact/ (the `<div>`s are showing just fine, but the required validation is now gone because I was messing with the `include_blank` that is generated from Contact Form 7 plugin)

Comment: Press "SEND MESSAGE" without filling/clicking anything else at http://lavertibrands.com/contact-drop-test/ to see that the required field validation is still there.

Comment: Don't add `select` html provided by me, just add `div`s and `script`

Comment: I got it fixed by mixing 2 scripts, it thanks to your contribution, help, and fast response. Thanks a lot!