# Contact Form 7: display/hide div on selection

Tags: jquery, css

i'm following this post [jquery show-hide DIV with CONTACT FORM 7 dropdown menu (select field)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21310114/jquery-show-hide-div-with-contact-form-7-dropdown-menu-select-field)
to create a display/hide depending on selection.

I just created the form, but then how to implement the jquery function? I've to create a html, head, body tags in the contact form 7 page? Beacause i'm trying but does not works.

```
<select id="reason">
<option>...</option>
<option value="I want to hire you">I want to hire you</option>
<option value="I want to ask you a question">I want to ask you a question</option>
    <option value="I want to say hello">I want to say hello</option>
</select>

<div id="I want to hire you" class="note">I am currently available</div>
<div id="I want to ask you a question" class="note">Feel free to ask</div>
<div id="I want to say hello" class="note">Get in touch</div>
```

jQuery

```
$('.note').hide();
$(document).on("change", "#reason", function () {
$('.note').hide();
var neededId = $(this).val();
var divToShow = $(".note").filter("[id='" + neededId + "']");
divToShow.show();
});
```

EDIT:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
$('.note').hide();

$(document).on("change", "#reason", function () {
$('.note').hide();
var neededId = $(this).val();
var divToShow = $(".note").filter("[id='" + neededId + "']");
divToShow.show();
});
</script>
<body>
<select id="reason">
<option>...</option>
<option value="I want to hire you">I want to hire you</option>
<option value="I want to ask you a question">I want to ask you a question</option>
<option value="I want to say hello">I want to say hello</option>
</select>

<div style="display: none;" id="I want to hire you" class="note">I am currently available</div>
<div style="display: none;" id="I want to ask you a question" class="note">Feel free to ask</div>
<div style="display: none;" id="I want to say hello" class="note">Get in touch</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement your jquery on a .js file. You may already have one on a js folder... you can copy paste it there.

Another solution could be to create a displayHide.js and add it to your wordpress theme.

You will have to go to your functions.php and use wp_enqueue_script to be able to use the js on your wp theme. Here is a link for you to know how to implement it: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script

Example:

```
<?php
    function my_scripts_method() {
      wp_enqueue_script(
        'custom-script',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/displayHide.js',
        array( 'jquery' )
      );
}

 add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method' );
?>
```

Implementing your js inside any contact form-7 file is not a good idea, given that at some point you will have to update your plugin and your custom code will be deleted.

Comment: I've edited the first post. So i'm doing wrong like this?

Comment: Well is not that you are doing it wrong, probably will work (depending on how jquery is loading for example), but the best solution will be to load all of you js from the same source, plus you are making sure that you are loading it after jquery has also load..